# Which test can I use to compare a "percentage structure" (of three categories) between two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

Let's assume I have 3 mutually exclusive options: A, B and C and 2 groups: X and Y.

In group X I have the following percentage structure:
A - 10 (10%)
B - 85 (85%)
C - 5  (5%)

In group Y it follows:
A - 20 (20%)
B - 70 (70%)
C - 10 (10%)

I'd like to compare the 2 groups not one by one, i.e. A_X vs. A_Y, B_X vs.B_Y and so on, but rather the entire "percentage structure".

Actually I can do this for just 2 items, by calculating % of one of them with respect to the sum (like number of successes). Exemplary R code (but I don't care about software) for comparing "A to B" between X and Y

```
> prop.test(x = c(10, 20), n = c(10+85, 20+70))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(10, 20) out of c(10 + 85, 20 + 70)
X-squared = 3.8322, df = 1, p-value = 0.05028
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2335402588 -0.0003778699
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.1052632 0.2222222
```

Now I can do the same for the "B to C".
I will get 2 results of tests.

But is there a statistical test (ideally if you could provide the formula/reference/book), that can compare the entire structure "A to B to C" in X vs. "A to B to C" in Y?

By the way is there anything like 2-way ANOVA for proportions/fractions? I think I could use a non-parametric test, like ANOVA-Type Statistis (ATS) or Aligned-Rank-Transform ANOVA (ART), which are both non-parametric approach to n-way ANOVA with interactions (not like just Kruskal-Wallis, which is just one-way), by treating the counts or fractions as ranked numbers. But maybe there's something dedicated? This way I could check, if:

- there are differences between the counts (A vs. B vs. C)
- there are differences between the groups (X vs. Y)
- there is an interaction between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chi-squared test of homogeneity.**

First, for a test of homogeneity you need *counts* throughout.
So suppose you have following table of counts
for 200 subjects altogether; two groups, three categories:

```
        A    B    C   Total
X      10   85    5     100
Y      20   70   10     100
Total  30  155   15     200
```

If you want to know whether Groups X and Y have
the same proportions for A, B and C, it seems
best to start with a chi-squared test of homogeneity. Its implementation in R gives the following results:

```
x = c(10, 85, 5);  y = c(20, 70, 10)
TBL = rbind(x, y);  TBL
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
x   10   85    5
y   20   70   10
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 6.4516, df = 2, p-value = 0.03972
```

The P-value of about 4% indicates that there
is (barely) a significant difference at the 5%
level of significance.

Expected counts reflect what one would expect if
groups X and Y are homogeneous. It is a good
idea to check to see that these counts are large enough
for the 'chi-squared' statistic to have a
chi-squared distribution. [The program will show
a warning message if they are too small.] One
hopes to see all expected counts greater than 5,
which is the case here.

```
chisq.test(TBL)$exp
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
x   15 77.5  7.5
y   15 77.5  7.5
```

If you get a significant P-value, it can be useful
to look at the Pearson residuals. The sum of squares of the Pearson residuals is the chi-squared statistic $6.4516,$ shown in the results above.

```
chisq.test(TBL)$resi
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
x -1.290994  0.8519428 -0.9128709
y  1.290994 -0.8519428  0.9128709
```

The largest of them may point the way to the most
interesting differences among sample proportions for the two groups. These might be explored in *ad hoc* tests. Usually, one looks for residuals with absolute values of about 2 or above,
but there are no such residuals here. However, in order to explore the idea, let's compare counts in A and B for the two groups. [It seems this may be essentially what you did with `prop.test` in your Question.] This particular result is not significant even at the 5% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL[,c(1,2)])$p.val
[1] 0.05027749
```

Moreover, in order to
avoid 'false discovery', from repeated analyses
of the same data, you should use some method (such
as Bonferroni's) to do multiple *ad hoc* tests at even lower
significance levels.

---

*Notes:* (1) If you had a lot more than 200 subjects overall, with about the same *sample proportions* as in your
`TBL`, you might see some additional significant
results.

For example, if you used fake data in
`TBL.FAKE`, with an imaginary 1000 subjects, then
both the overall chi-squared test and the *ad hoc*
test on just counts A and B would be highly significant with P-values near $0.$  This
illustration with fake data emphasizes that you
need to analyze **counts, not proportions.**

Bar charts of data in `TBL` and `TBL.FAKE`
would look *exactly the same,* except possibly for counts shown on a vertical axis or total counts shown in a footnote.

```
TBL.FAKE = 5*TBL
TBL.FAKE
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
x   50  425   25
y  100  350   50

sum(TBL.FAKE)
[1] 1000

chisq.test(TBL.FAKE)$p.val
[1] 9.89123e-08
chisq.test(TBL.FAKE[ ,c(1,2)])$p.val
[1] 2.198613e-06
```

(2) You may want to look in a standard elementary or intermediate-level applied
statistics text if you are not familiar with such chi-squared tests.

Also, there are many examples of chi-squared tests on this site. You might use the search line at the top of the page to search for 'chi-squared test, homogeneity'. You might start by looking at
the pages marked as 'Relevant' in the margin of this page.